# Runtime complexity of searching for value in std::map using brackets?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am wondering if using `map[key]` to search for a value in the map (that already exists in the map) is constant-time or logarithmic-time in C++. I know that map.find(key) is logarithmic, but if the item already exists then will it be O(1) or still O(log(n))?

Example:

```
m[1] = 2;
if (m[1] == 2)
  ...
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at#Complexity

Comment: It's logarithmic, just like find. The B-52s never had a bassist, I'm sure you know that.

Comment: whether it exists or not, the map has to find the position in either case. How else would it determine if the element is present or not?

Comment: `std::map` is logarithmic being a tree, `std::unordered_map` is constant being a hash-map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `operator[]` is not just searching for a value, it is potentially adding a new one to the map:

> *Effects:* Equivalent to: `return try_emplace(x).first->second;`

- [[map.access] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/map.access#1)

The complexity of `try_emplace` is the same as the complexity of `emplace`, and this is documented in the *AssociativeContainer* requirement:

> `a_uniq.emplace(args)`
>
> [...]
>
> *Complexity:* Logarithmic.

- [[associative.reqmts] `emplace`](https://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#lib:emplace,ordered_associative_containers)

In general, all random access into a `std::map` has logarithmic complexity. The complexity of `operator[]` and thus `emplace` is not affected by whether there already exists an element in the map either; it is always logarithmic.

The only way to improve this is by using some member function which lets you provide a position, such as `std::map::emplace_hint`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::map::operator[]` is specified to have complexity `O(log N)` in either case. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at#Complexity. The `O(log N)` is to find the position of the element. Whether the element is already there does not change that.

---

The only way I can understand your question is that you assume the insertion to be the expensive part. And when the element is present, nothing has to be inserted into the map. However, the insertion is not the expensive part of calling `operator[]`. Once the position is known the insertion is actually rather cheap. Consider [`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert). It has overloads (4-6) that let you pass a position `pos` and

> Inserts value in the position as close as possible to the position just prior to `pos`.

Those are

> Amortized constant if the insertion happens in the position just after (until C++11)before (since C++11) pos, logarithmic in the size of the container otherwise.

---

TL;DR: No. The `O(log N)` is caused by finding the postition where the element would be. That doesnt change when the element is present already. On the other hand, when an element is not present in the map, insertion at an already known position is only amortized constant.